# Keyboard input works on some occasions but not others

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I've been trying to learn Unity these past couple of weeks. As a starter project I decided to try and replicate the mobile game Pop the Lock. Right now, I'm having some problems with my keyboard inputs that I just can't figure out how to solve.

This is how my game screen looks: [GameScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djILo.png). The red bar is the Player and the yellow circle is the Target. As the game progresses, the Player rotates around the ring towards the Target.

Basically, if the Player and the Target are touching AND the Player presses the Space Key at the exact same time, the Player is supposed to gain a point. The Target is also supposed to be destroyed, and a new Target is supposed to randomly be spawned in somewhere on the game screen. At the moment, this system works ... most of the time. About 80% of the time my code operates as it should, but around 20% of the time my code doesn't register when player presses the space key as the two collide. Here's my code:

```
public class Target: MonoBehaviour {

   public GameObject target; 

   void Update () {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
        Debug.Log("SPACE PRESSED!!");
     }
   }

  private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision) {
    Debug.Log("Collision!");
  }

  private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) {

     // This is the part that sometimes isn't registering:
     if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {

        Debug.Log("HIT!!");
        Score.score++;
    
        // Code to spawn new Target on random place in the ring:
        // Seems to be working as intended:
        
        float distance = 2.034822f;
        float x = Random.Range(-2f, 2f);
        float y = Mathf.Pow(distance,2) - Mathf.Pow(x,2);
        y =  Mathf.Sqrt(y);
        float[] options = {y, -y};
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, 2); 
        y = options[randomIndex];
        Vector3 vector = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        GameObject newTarget = Instantiate(target, vector, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(gameObject);
     }

  }

}
```

As you can see I have Log statements that print something every time the player and the target are touching, every time the space key is pressed, and every time the space key is pressed while they are touching. This is how the console looks like when everything is working : [Image One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QFjO.png). This is what the console looks like when my code isn't working : [Image Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKWaf.png).

So even when it isn't working, the collision and the key press are still registered at the exact same time. But for some reason the hit itself isn't registered (so the if condition isn't passed). Because of this I'm quite confident that it's not just input delay or me pressing the key at the wrong time. As I mentioned above, this only happens about 20% of the time, which makes it even more confusing to me. The Target has a trigger collider2D and it also has a dynamic RigidBody2D with gravity scale set to 0 (as I was told it should). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(How my collider and rigidbody look: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blnRU.png))

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`! And what you should rather do is tag `unity3d` as this is the main framework/API you are using here

Comment: You should probably look at https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html and note that Triggers occur as Physics events and Inputs are processed as an Update (using script order) as Game Logic.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is to set a flag to becomes true while you are pressing the key in the update loop, so the update loop will convert to something like:

```
private bool isSpacePressed = false;

update() {
  isSpacePressed = false;
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
    isSpacePressed = true;
  }
}
```

so every loop the flag will be set to false except if you are pressing the space bar and the OnTriggerStay2D while become something like

```
OnTriggerStay2D () {
  if(isSpacePressed){
    .. do magic.. 
  }
}
```

Look that I replace the Input.GetKeyDown('space') to Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) I recommend using this one to avoid typing errors